# how does one see the CBOE VIX index on Google Finance?

Tags: options, volatility, etn

How does one see the CBOE VIX index on Google Finance?  What is a symbol I can use?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, I don't believe they offer it. 
[Yahoo does](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5EVIX).

A google for google finance VIX turns up people asking the question, but no quote on google.

Comment: Yah, I couldn't find it either, which is frustrating to me because I like having my list of stocks I watch on Google because I like their graphing capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can pull up the VIX index on Google Finance by entering [INDEXCBOE:VIX](https://www.google.com/finance?authuser=0&q=indexcboe%3avix)